# Fetch data from cursor.execute(sql) to python list with filtering the specific variable value in sql

Tags: python, sql, fetchrequest

There is a dataset that has 70 million row records in sql-oracle, i execute it in python with:

> cursor.execute(sql_q)

It is ok to take whole 70 million rows data to python with cursor.execute. However, converting list or dataframe takes really long time and inefficient.

Thus, i want to split data into 20 parts by the rule; as seen in below there are many rows which belong to same customer. These rows have same customer value must be in same table part.

```
CUST_ID CUST  VERSION   …
1        AAA    1       …
1        AAA    2       …
1        AAA    3       …
1        AAA    4       …
1        AAA    5       …
1        AAA    6       …
2        BBB    1       …
2        BBB    2       …
2        BBB    3       …
2        BBB    4       …
3        CCC    1       …
3        CCC    2       …
3        CCC    3       …
3        CCC    4       …
3        CCC    5       …
3        CCC    6       …
3        CCC    7       …
…         ..            …
7000000  XXX    1       …
7000000  XXX    2       …
7000000  XXX    3       …
7000000  XXX    4       …
7000000  XXX    5       …
7000000  XXX    6       …
```

However there is a problem; i cannot split data in sql query with "where CUST_ID between 1 and 350000" etc. because sql query doesn't have numeric customer id (CUST_ID) by itself . I had to form a variable in sql query as CUST_ID. (I have only select permission to that table so i create CUST_ID on the fly. )Therefore i need to split data in python after cursor.execute:

For instance, there are 7 million unique customers. I want to fetch them by splitting data into 20 part according to CUST_ID. Because same CUST_ID's must be in same part.

1. split data set has rows -> CUST_ID's between 1 and 350.000
2. split data set has rows -> CUST_ID's between 350.001 and 700.001
   ... (so on)
   I wanted to use below code:

```
cursor.execute(sql_q)
while True:
  
    rows = cursor.fetchmany(batch_size)
    if not rows:
        break
 
    for row in rows:        
        print(row)
```

but, i couldnt find out how to add CUST_ID conditions while fetching (such as fetch while CUST_ID between 1 and 350000 etc)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need an artificial `customer_id` or there's another field for batching (looks like `cust` should do the work)? Or if you're ok to merge not corellated records (where single customer can be in different batches) there's an option to batch by `rowid`, for example, which will be fast.

Comment: Unfortunately there isnt any another variable instead of cust_id. I also thought rowid but same customer must be in same table, rowid cant unsure it. Because thereafter i will make same processes on the level of customer.